# Input vector representation vs output vector representation in word2vec

Tags: neural-networks, natural-language, word2vec, word-embeddings

In word2vec's CBOW and skip-gram models, how does choosing word vectors from $W$ (input word matrix) vs. choosing word vectors from $W'$ (output word matrix) impact the quality of the resulting word vectors?

CBOW:

[image]

Skip-gram:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Garten et al. {1} compared word vectors obtained by *adding* input word vectors with output word vectors, vs. word vectors obtained by *concatenating* input word vectors with output word vectors. In their experiments, concatenating yield significantly better results:

[image]

The video lecture {2} recommends to average input word vectors with output word vectors, but doesn't compare against concatenating input word vectors with output word vectors.

---

References:

- {1} Garten, J., Sagae, K., Ustun, V., & Dehghani, M. (2015, June). [Combining Distributed Vector Representations for Words](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=Combining+Distributed+Vector+Representations+for+Words&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C22). In Proceedings of NAACL-HLT (pp. 95-101).
- {2} Stanford CS224N: NLP with Deep Learning by Christopher Manning | Winter 2019 | Lecture 2 – Word Vectors and Word Senses. https://youtu.be/kEMJRjEdNzM?t=1565 ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20191130201551/http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs224n/))